# read many files and create animation-python

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyfits

I wrote script which create animation (movie) from fits files. One file has size 2.8 MB and the no. of files is 9000. 
Here is code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import os
import pyfits
import glob
import re



Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=15, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)

global numbers
numbers=re.compile(r'(\d+)')

def numericalSort(value):
    parts = numbers.split(value)
    parts[1::2] = map(int, parts[1::2])
    return parts


image_list=glob.glob('/kalib/*.fits')

image_list= sorted(image_list,key=numericalSort)
print image_list
fig = plt.figure("movie")
img = []

for i in range(0,len(image_list)):

    hdulist = pyfits.open(image_list[i])
    im = hdulist[0].data
    img.append([plt.imshow(im,cmap=plt.cm.Greys_r)])


ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig,img, interval=20, blit=True,repeat_delay=0)
ani.save('movie.mp4', writer=writer)
```

I think that my problem is when I create array img[]...I have 8 GB RAM and when the RAM is full my operating system terminate python script.

My question is:
How I can read 9000 files and create animation? Is possible create some buffer or some parallel processing?

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use `ffmpeg`. With the command `image2pipe` you don't have to load all the images into your RAM but rather one by one (i think) into a pipe.

In addition to that, `ffmpeg` allows you to manipulate the video (framerate, codec, format, etc...).

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off creating your animation with FuncAnimation instead of ArtistAnimation, as explained in [ArtistAnimation vs FuncAnimation matplotlib animation matplotlib.animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22158395/artistanimation-vs-funcanimation-matplotlib-animation-matplotlib-animation) FuncAnimation is more efficient in its memory usage. You might want to experiment with FuncAnimation's save_count parameter as well, check out the API documentation for examples.

Comment: Thanks for answer...but I think that this is not my problem ...I have problem with reading data array from files to img[] array...Animation is created when I have readed array img[]

Comment: Right but the problem is you're not taking the right approach in the first place. You shouldn't be making a *list* of rendered images with imshow, because each one of those is taking up memory. FuncAnimation allows you to render one frame at a time on an as-needed basis without rendering all images at once. Perhaps you could be clearer about what you are hoping to accomplish, but making a large list of image artists isn't the way.

Comment: As a followup, the reason what you're doing works for say, a line plot or something like that, is that lines and polygons and the like are trivial to represent in memory and animate. Whole images are a different story, and when you call imshow you're using memory for each pixel of each frame. A naïve approach won't work.